# How to tell when gradle is being run from AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to build some hacks into my gradle build file so that Android Studio understands some things. I don't need these hacks when I run the build from the command line directory. Is there a way to detect when the build is being run from within Android Studio? Maybe through environment variables, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `gradle -P blah=val` from command line and in your build.gradle use `project.hasProperty("blah")` or `project.getProperty("test")` or `if (blah ... )`  to decide whether run your hack or not.

**Updated:**

OK I found the direct way :)

```
def env = System.getProperties()
if (env['com.android.studio.gradle.project.path'] != null) {
    // build from Android Studio, do magic here
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but it'd be better if there was a way built in to Android Studio. I don't want to have to remember to set the property each time I run the build.

Comment: It looks like `android.injected.invoked.from.ide` is set in the environment [as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/093gmtWUsm8).

Comment: Does this still work w/ Android Studio 2.0?  those two environment variables (android.injected.invoked.from.ide and com.android.studio.gradle.project.path) aren't set when I compile from Android Studio :-(

Comment: nice one. I need this thing !!

Answer (score 7):

With **AndroidStudio 2.1.1**, you can use the **idea.platform.prefix** property:

```
def sysprops = System.getProperties()
if (sysprops['idea.platform.prefix'] != null) {
    // Built from AndroidStudio
} else {
    // Built from command line
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Jake Wharton suggests `android.injected.invoked.from.ide` [to speed butterknife at development time by using reflection](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/tree/master/butterknife-reflect#usage):

```
dependencies {
  if (properties.containsKey('android.injected.invoked.from.ide')) {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-reflect:<version>'
  } else {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:<version>'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:<version>'
  }
}
```

From [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/1038080688069722112):

> Hey ButterKnife users: I'm working on a reflection-based implementation for use during development so the annotation processor is not needed.

A [follow-up](https://twitter.com/TevinJeffrey/status/1038092278215131137):

> What is this? A property from (link: http://gradle.properties) gradle.properties?

The [answer we want](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/1038096096046854144):

> No it's added by the IDE

Answer (score 0):

Using the Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
if (System.getProperty("idea.active") == "true") {
    println("Running in Android Studio or some other IDEA based ide")
}
// Else the property will be null
```