# Is there a way to programmatically distinguish between IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kts

I would like to include different parts of a settings.gradle.kts file depending on whether a project is compiled with IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.

For my purposes, I only need to know if the project is compiled with Android Studio or not, as certain mobile-specific modules of the project can only be compiled with Android Studio.

Since the modules are distinguished in the settings gradle kotlin script file, I hope to find a solution where a simple if includes those modules accordingly. Thus far I've been commenting out the relevant modules when working in IDEA.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769034/8203759

Comment: is this any different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324880/detect-ide-environment-with-gradle/64769034#64769034 ? isn't this just a duplicate ?

Comment: It is a duplicate question, but the answers there did not work for me

Comment: After searching the properties that ended up being the answer, I found another question that is a more accurate duplicate with the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856122/9869967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relevant properties that are set in Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA:

- `idea.paths.selector`, which in default instalations has a value such as "AndroidStudioPreview2021.1" or "IntelliJIdea2021.2", so you could use this if you needed to know if it was either:

```kotlin
val pathSelector: String? = System.getProperty("idea.paths.selector")
if(pathSelector == null) // Some other IDE or none
else if(pathSelector.startsWith("AndroidStudio"))
// Do Android Studio specific things
else if(pathSelector.startsWith("IntelliJIdea"))
// Do IntelliJ IDEA specific things
else // Some other Jetbrains IDE
```

- `idea.platform.prefix`, which seems to only be set for Android Studio, with a value of "AndroidStudio", so it works for my case:

```kotlin
if(System.getProperty("idea.platform.prefix") == "AndroidStudio")
   // Do Android Studio specific things
else // Any other IDE or none
```

Thank you [@Konstantin Annikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8203759/konstantin-annikov) for notifying me about another similar question that was never fully answered but was on the right track (using properties)